# Nginx Forward Trailling Slash Apps

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I know there are lot many questions regarding this, but I couldn't find any such specify question or answer

I have 3 AngularJS app

- App1 ( URL - app1.domain )
- App2 ( URL - app2.domain )
- App3 ( URL - app3.domain )

All of these apps have their own styles, scripts and views ( Angular views ) directory. I'm trying to configure nginx in such a way that all these 3 apps will be served as below

```
domain/app1/#/
domain/app2/#/
domain/app3/#/
```

I'm able to proxy the requests, however, the same fails while loading the resource files and angular views

**Example:** When I load domain/app1, all views requests are being made to domain/views/main.html and not domain/app1/views/main.html

I tried adding a base tag to the index.html, this helped while loading resource files and it is not working for angular view files

```
#nginx configuration

server {

listen 80;
server_name domain.com;

  location /app1 {
           proxy_pass app1.domain;
  }

  location /app2 {
           proxy_pass app2.domain;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should it be `domain/app1/*.*` on your HTTP-Requests when you configure your domain root to that folder: `domain/app1/`? A request on `domain/views/main.html `  sound fine to me, whats the problem? If you want that folders to be included in your URL you should configure your location like: `location / { proxy_pass app2.domain; }`

Comment: @lin As per my nginx configuration, this doesn't exist - `domain/views/main.html`

Comment: @lin i'm hosting them on netlify, those 3 apps are 3 different sites, with different URLs'

Comment: So what is the correct path for `views/main.html` by starting at your root directory ?

Comment: @lin The path is `views/main.html`. But the 3 apps are overlapping. I am looking out for a solutions in nginx, so that when domain/app1 is making a request for a view file (request url will be - `domain/views/main.html`), the same has to be redirected to `domain/app1/views/main.html`

Comment: You have three client-side apps making overlapping requests - `nginx` is probably not the best place to try to resolve this. Your client-side apps need to be configured to stay within their allocated sub-directory.

Comment: Hey @RichardSmith, thanks for your suggestion, I'm considering this too. But my app's are different from each others and require certain specific build steps. Any further suggestions here?